# Why would my Google Maps plugin KML feature only work in certain regions? It works in New York and France, but not in Texas

Tags: wordpress, plugins

My client's website has a page (https://txdish.com/coverage/coverage-maps/) that uses WPGoogle Maps to show satellite signal coverage with KML layers. There is a menu on the left to toggle the different coverage areas on and off. The layers seem to work for some people, but not others.

I have been working with the app developer for weeks now. He got it working for me and my client just over a week ago (Even though it was working for him the whole time). Yesterday, it stopped working again. I tried using a VPN and it worked. I disabled the VPN and it stopped working. I'm at a loss.

I can provide code as requested.

It's tough to reproduce any errors because I'm not seeing any in my console.